# How to convert u'\xd0' to d0 in hex?

Tags: python, python-unicode

I got this simple but difficult problem in Python. For unknown reason with pypyjs, I got my binary buffer as u'\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1...'. By the look of it, I knew it would be alright if it is a binary stream of 'd0cf 11e0 a1...'. I wondered how do I do the conversion? What I need is this:

```
u'\xd0' -> d0 # integer value please
u'\xcf' -> cf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are unicode code points. They aren't binary data at all, and you can't be receiving them like that; something is doing some conversion at your end.

You can certainly convert them to hex values:

```
hex(ord(u'\xd0'))
```

but I think your problem lies elsewhere in your code.